# Include the cc payment template in other template

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I'm working on a credit card (CC) payment module.
I see that Magento 2 already offers a [template for CC payments](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html) but it contains only the form needed for the payment.
It does not have the radio button that I can check during checkout.
So if I create my payment method renderer like this.

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
               template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form'
            },
            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },
            getCode: function() {
                return 'payment_code_here';
            }
        });
    }
);
```

my payment section in the checkout would look like this (Check/money order is an other payment method):

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

I know that I can create my own template and define the method renderer like this:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: '<Vendor>_<Module>/payment/form'
            },
            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },
            getCode: function() {
                return 'payment_code_here';
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And in that template add the markup for the radio button and just copy/paste the default cc-form template where I need it, but I'm trying to avoid that.
Is there a way to include an other template inside my template?
This may be more of a KO question than Magento.

To explain it better...

My custom template looks like this:

```
<my custom code here />
<code copied from cc-form /> 
<some other custom code here />
```

I want to replace `<code copied from cc-form />` with an include of some kind that will fetch the content from `cc-form`.

Comment: Marius, How can i use Magento 2  template for CC payments in my custom payment module.?
I wanted to show a CC form on checkout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, do you mean you want to call a KO HTML template from another template/module?

If so the I believe the following markup works (unable to test currently):

```
<!-- ko template: "Package_Namespace/template-name" --><!-- /ko -->
```

Or alternatively you can define the template in an object and pass a property like so:

```
<!-- ko template: propertyExample --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Yes, I want to include in my template an other template. I will try it and come back with the results.

Comment: Cool, I've just added an alternative way using properties.

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy. Thanks. I will give you the fake internet points in about 23h, when I'ma allowed to do it.

Comment: The KO implementation is slowly growing on me, at first it was terrifying. Thanks, I love me some fake internet points.

Comment: @BenCrook helpful info.